# Displaying a PDF Document in ASP.net page

Tags: asp.net, pdf

Can anyone suggest me which is the best way of displaying a PDF document in an aspx page. I want users to use zoom functionality while viewing the pdf document.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the PDF in memory use one of the Stream objects to break it down to a byte array (possibly using the .ToArray() function of the MemoryStream class). In this example below the byte array is called data:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";

Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Edit: This approach works well if all you want to do is serve up a PDF. After reading some of the comments I realized the question was more focused on showing a PDF inside a section of a webpage. Another alternative I have used is an embed tag that references a codefile function. In this case, if you have the PDF on a disk drive you can use

```
<embed id="Embed1" src='<%# pdfLocation() %>' runat="server" name="pdfLoad"></embed>
```

Where the function pdfLocation returns a string representation of the location of the PDF file.

Comment: I opt for this approach, setting the appropriate content type to force the browser to render the correct mime type.

Answer (score 1):

Just serve the PDF as a standard PDF.

Comment: Daniel, Thanks But I dont want to open it in a new window. I want it to show in some kind of viewer

Comment: You could do it in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Flash-based solution would work best for you in this situation, such as [Adobe FlashPaper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/).  There is no dependency on the browser having a PDF plug-in that displays the document in the browser, such as Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader.  It supports zooming, searching, printing, full-screen mode, and text selection, and you don't have to rely on a third-party hosted solution like Scribd.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/EmbedPDFinWebpages.aspx), or [these](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB346GB346&q=embed+pdf+in+aspx&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=) any help?

Edit - Thats assuming you want to embed otherwise as Daniel suggests, just serve it direct to the user.